# implement Search Bar to filter list from Listview

Tags: java, android, string, listview, searchbar

I am making app and try to do Search Function to filter data from list view. my data from list view is supported for multilanguage. if user type a word in their language data in list view will display. I don't know how to do with search bar. below is my code:

```
 listView = findViewById(R.id.Lv);
    listView.setSelected(true);
    share = findViewById(R.id.share);
    timkiembar = findViewById(R.id.timkiembar);
timkiembar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {



        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
 String[] storyname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stories_names);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this,R.layout.row,R.id.row_txt,storyname);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(Reading.this,web.class);
            intent.putExtra("story_key",position);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

and below is my String.xml to display in listview:

```
 <string-array name="stories_names">
    <item name="bai1">@string/bai1</item>
    <item name="bai2">@string/bai2</item>
    <item name="bai3">@string/bai3</item>
    <item name="bai4">@string/bai4</item>
    <item name="bai5">@string/bai5</item>
    <item name="bai6">@string/bai6</item>
    <item name="bai7">@string/bai7</item>
    <item name="bai8">@string/bai8</item>
    <item name="bai9">@string/bai9</item>
    <item name="bai10">@string/bai10</item>
    <item name="bai11">@string/bai11</item>
    <item name="bai12">@string/bai12</item>
    <item name="bai13">@string/bai13</item>

  <string name="bai1">1.   Japanese Daycares</string>
<string name="bai2">2.   Bentos</string>
<string name="bai3">3.   Okinawa</string>
<string name="bai4">4.   Japanese Wedding Ceremonies</string>
<string name="bai5">5.   Crayon Shin Chan</string>
<string name="bai6">6.   Japanese Music</string>
<string name="bai7">7.   Having a baby in Japan</string>

<string name="bai8">8.     Cultured Meat Industry Addresses Mass Production</string>
<string name="bai9">9.     Thousands Lose Homes and Hopes</string>
<string name="bai10">10.       Scholz Succeed Merkel As German Chancellor</string>
<string name="bai11">11.       80th Anniversary Of Pearl Harbor Attack</string>
<string name="bai12">12.       U.S. Diplomat To Boycott Beijing Games</string>
<string name="bai13">13.       2021’s Kanji Character Is ‘Gold’</string>
<string name="bai14">14.       Kishida takes office as 100th Japan PM</string>
```

Can anyone please help me how to make code to filter data from list view? thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

Filtering cannot be used with fixed size array, so first change `String[] storyname = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stories_names);` to `List<String> storyname = Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stories_names));`

Then the code for filtering:

```
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) 
{
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (ArrayAdapter<String>) listView.getAdapter();
        adapter.getFilter().filter(s);
}
```

Comment: Thansk, it worked.